# Primefaces Lazyload + datatable + lazyDataModel

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I did my research, found many problems with `lazyload` and dataTable, but none explains the problem I'm having. I actually already posted this problem on Primefaces website and got no answers. Either my problem is too stupid or too complex.

We updated our primefaces library from 3.1.1 to 3.5, and our `LazyLoad` datatables stopped working. Basically the DataModel has changed, so I implemented a new one based on Primefaces Showcase scenario.

> The error is: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Lazy loading is
>   not implemented.

The thing is it is implemented by the class `LazyMethodDataModel` as you see the code below.
When I debug, the constructor is called but the error is throwed before the load method is called.

Any thoughts? thank you in advance. Should you need more information, please let me know.

```
 public class LazyMethodDataModel_new extends LazyDataModel<Produto> {
@Override
public List<Produto> load(int first, int pageSize, List multiSortMeta, Map filters) { 
   generic.setRow(first);
   generic.setPage(pageSize);
  List objts = (List) Reflection.getObjectByInvokeMethod(crud, method, generic);
   return objts;

}
public LazyMethodDataModel_new(CrudFacade crud,String method,String   methodCount,GenericModel<?> generic) {

    this.crud = crud;
    this.generic = generic;        
    this.method = method;        
    size = (Integer) Reflection.getObjectByInvokeMethod(crud, methodCount, generic);
    setRowCount(size);
}
@Override
public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
    /*
     * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
     * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
     */
    if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
        super.setRowIndex(-1);
    }
    else
        super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
}}
```

Front END

```
<p:dataTable id="listProduto" var="model" value="#{adminProdutoBean.lazyDataModel}" 
             paginator="true" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" lazy="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two `load` methods in LazyDataModel:

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}

public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String,String> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}
```

and you need implement one more (also, as I remember it is enough to implement first one).

Comment: Hello, ty for you answer. If you see the first code, I already implemented load method, also if you check primefaces showcase example, they also implemented only one load method.

Comment: Are you saying I'm obligated to implement both load methods ?

Comment: For my project (with 3.5) only load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) implemented (not the same as in your code example)

Comment: hmmm understood, I guess I implemented the wrong one. I'm gonna try to implement the other one and see! tyvm!

Comment: Hey there, I implemented that method as you said and it worked! it calls load method but the paginator doesn't work. In the documentation it says everytime user presses a pagination button the datagrid should call load method, but that's not happening! any ideas ?

Comment: Internal exception, none. Firebug says there is an error in the page.

Comment: TypeError: a[h].refresh is not a function

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have enabled multi sorting you have to overwrite the other load method.

```
    public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}
```

The load method you try to overwrite is only if you use multisorting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29946? It worked for me (except for selection features, on which I am working on).